# Chart a line graph using LINQPad

Tags: c#, linqpad

LINQPad can plot the line graph using anonymous arrays. I do have JSON content with datetime (entrytime) and numerical value (cumulative gains). How can I adapt LINQPad to chart the JSON content?

```
void Main()
{
    // You can optionally specify a series type such as Pie, Area, Spline, etc.:

    var customers = new[]
    {
        new { Name = "John", TotalOrders = 100 },
        new { Name = "Mary", TotalOrders = 130 },
        new { Name = "Sara", TotalOrders = 140 },
        new { Name = "Paul", TotalOrders = 125 },
    };

    customers.Chart(c => c.Name, c => c.TotalOrders, Util.SeriesType.Line).Dump();

    string json = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"entryTime\": \"2019-01-08T00:00:01\",\r\n    \"gains\": -0.00071,\r\n    \"cumulativegains\": -0.00071\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"entryTime\": \"2019-01-08T05:00:01\",\r\n    \"gains\": -0.00102,\r\n    \"cumulativegains\": -0.00102\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"entryTime\": \"2019-01-08T09:00:01\",\r\n    \"gains\": -0.00113,\r\n    \"cumulativegains\": -0.00113\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"entryTime\": \"2019-01-08T10:31:19\",\r\n    \"gains\": -0.00236,\r\n    \"cumulativegains\": -0.00236\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"entryTime\": \"2019-01-09T20:21:34\",\r\n    \"gains\": -0.00262,\r\n    \"cumulativegains\": -0.00262\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"entryTime\": \"2019-01-11T16:00:01\",\r\n    \"gains\": -0.00075,\r\n    \"cumulativegains\": -0.00075\r\n  },\r\n ]";
    json.Dump();
    List<trades2plot> jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<trades2plot>>(json);

    jsonData.Dump();
}

public class trades2plot
{
    //public int TradeNumber;
    //public DateTime initializedTime;
    public DateTime entryTime;
    //public DateTime exitTime;
    public double gains;
    public double cumulativegains;
    public trades2plot() { }
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
```

Comment: Your question is less about Linqpad and more about deserializing a json string. Do you know what the type looks like ahead of time?

Comment: I deserialized it but cannot figure out how to chart it.  when i dump jsonData i get can see the data

Comment: fixed it so i can see the chart

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
jsonData.Chart(c=>c.entryTime,c=>c.cumulativegains, Util.SeriesType.Line).Dump();
```

will enable plotting it as a line chart from JSON.